# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Tags: summation, closed-form

What is the closed form of
 $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
 as a function of $x$ and $n$?

Knowing that it converges to $e^x$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: If the sum is finite, then you will end up with a regular polynomial, and I don't think there's any better way of writing it than your sum, or equivalently $$1 + x + \frac12x^2 + \cdots + \frac1{n!}x^n$$

Comment: @Arthur you just expanded sigma!

Comment: There is no closed form for this finite sum. In particular doesnt exist a closed form for a finite sum of simple factorials (exceptions are some kind of binomial summations).

Comment: @Masacroso Y there is not for factorials?

Comment: For finite $n$ there is no closed form (except the polynomial) made of elementary functions. A closed form thanks to the special function "Incomplete Gamma" is :  $$\frac{e^x}{n!}\Gamma(n+1\:,\:x)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{ \Gamma (n+1,x)}{n!}e^x$$ where appears [the incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Do not worry : you will learn about it sooner or later.